# Is there any way that I can track a villager trade and execute a command when an item is traded

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a minecraft map and basically what I want is to execute a command when a player trades an item with the villager. (This is a custom villager with custom items not a random villager). I haven't tried anything yet, but what I was thinking of is a scoreboard that counts how many times the trade got used. If someone could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK with using command blocks, a quick search online revealed [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/h8tek4/how_to_detect_a_villager_trade/), citing [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancement/JSON_format#minecraft:villager_trade); apparently solving your very issue.

Emphasis added:

> > i want to detect when i do a trade with a villager. there is maybe a way to do it if i use data when i do a trade there is an nbt that change called uses but and i try to write the command it doesn't work any idea's?
>
> Oh, yea, easy peasy… There's an advancement trigger that's made for just this!
>
> ```
> {
>   "criteria": {
>     "requirement": {
>       "trigger": "minecraft:villager_trade",
>       "conditions": {
>         "item": {
>           "item": "minecraft:diamond"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> …
>
> If you're just looking to detect just one villager **and run some commands as that villager**, (for some custom map NPC or something) it would be very easy to just have:
>
> ```
> data modify storage temp NPC_1.uses set value []
> data modify storage temp NPC_1.uses append from entity <NPC #1> Offers.Recipes[0].uses
> data modify storage temp NPC_1.uses append from entity <NPC #1> Offers.Recipes[1].uses
> data modify storage temp NPC_1.uses append from entity <NPC #1> Offers.Recipes[2].uses
>
> ... and so on...
>
> execute store success score .changed int run data modify storage map NPC_1.uses set from storage temp NPC_1.uses
> execute if score .changed matches 1 run tellraw @a {"text":"NPC #1 was traded with."}
> execute if score .changed matches 1 as <NPC #1> run say "It's true, a player traded with me."
> ```

Comment: Thank you it really helped!